# How do I display specific key value pairs from a hash in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, hash, controller

I have a hash in my controller that a view takes data from to display.  In the tutorials I've seen, I've learned how to display each of the key, value pairs from a hash...but how do I display only the key,value pairs I want?

```
    creating the hash in the controller
    @app = {'title' => title, 'description' => description,
            'active' => active, 'featured'=> featured,
            'partner'=>partner
            }

    view: this displays each of the key,value pairs
    <% @app.each do |key, value| %>
        <li><%= "#{key}: #{value}" %>
    <% end %>

    tried this in the view just to display title, but isn't working
    <% @app.select do |ind_app| %>
        <strong><%= ind_app["title"] %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display the title, just ask for the title! No need to loop, you can directly access all values of a hash like this :

```
<strong><%= @app['title'] %></strong>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to get the pairs you want first. Try the following

```
<% @app.slice('title', 'active').each do |key, value| %>
    <li><%= "#{key}: #{value}" %>
<% end %>
```

This will only show the title and active part of the hash